# Embedding an base64 encoded image into Dash Data Table

Tags: python, image, plotly-dash

I am hoping to embed an image as a data:URI into a Dash Datatable as in the example below.  I borrowed the embedding from this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1199393/is-it-possible-to-directly-embed-an-image-into-a-markdown-document).  I am creating the images on the fly using another library not included in the code below.  When I run the Dash server using

```
python app.py
```

I get a data table with the encoded string and not an image.  I thought using the 'presentation': 'markdown' (in the columns section of the [dash documentation](https://dash.plot.ly/datatable/reference)) would work but unfortunately not.

I also tried wrapping the url in a dash html.Img component but that did not seem to work either.

Any help on this would be appreciated! Thank you

```
import dash
import dash_table
import pandas as pd


url1 = '![Hello World](data:image/png;base64,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)'

data = [['Item 1', url1], ['Item 2', url1]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Image']) 

app = dash.Dash(__name__)


app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": 'Name', "id": 'Name'},
    {
            'id': 'Image',
            'name': 'Image',
            'presentation': 'markdown',
        },
    ],
    #fixed_columns={ 'headers': True, 'data': 1 },
    data=df.to_dict('records'),

)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: if I change the url1 to ``` url1 = '![s](src=data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...)' ``` I get a broken image icon in the table. I aslo see that the html image element is activated in this case, however looks like some sort of formatting issue ``` <img src="src=data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K..." alt="s"> ```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like adding an assets folder locally and dumping image files in it works with respect to display

If I replace the `url1` line in the above code with something like the following:

```
url1 = '![myImage-1](assets/test.png)'
```

Ressources should be placed in a specified `assets` folder as [described here](https://dash.plotly.com/reference#dash.dash).
Example:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, assets_folder='assets')
```

Note: `assets_folder='assets'` is the default value. See also this from the api reference:

> `assets_folder`
>
> a path, relative to the current working directory, for extra files to be used in the browser. Default `'assets'`. All `.js` and `.css` files will be loaded immediately unless excluded by `assets_ignore`, and other files such as images will be served if requested.

An image will display in each row of the table.  Ideally the data uri would work and I would prefer that approach, but I figured I would post this for now as a potential answer.

Comment: Hey Dennis, I tried implementing this exactly, and I get: ```![myImage-1](Assets/test2.png)``` under the Image column. Did you have to preprocess the image beforehand?

Comment: Placing ressources in `assets` was the only way for me to make the dash app find a simple png app.

Answer (score 1):

(NOTE: Please take into consideration that this approach leaves you open to an XSS vulnerability)

I've had the same problem which I've now managed to solve (One thing to note, I'm doing this using the Django framework, but it shouldn't matter).

My approach was to create a list of dicts (in a variable called ***columns_format***, you can call it whatever you want) where I defined the column names and id, and in the dict (where the ***id*** is equal to ***‘icons’***, again yours can be called something different) is where you must first insert the parameter ***presentation*** and equal it to ***‘markdown’***.

```
columns_format = [
    dict(id = 'icons', name = '', presentation='markdown'),
    dict(id = 'symbol', name='Symbol'),
    dict(id = 'name', name='Coins'),
```

Once you have specified your columns in the ***columns_format*** variable you must then set the ***markdown_options*** parameter to ***‘html’: True***, and then set the ***columns*** parameter equal to the ***columns_format*** variable created earlier.

```
app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    markdown_options = {
        'html': True
    },
    data = coins_df,
    columns = columns_format,
)
```

What must happen (incase you are referencing an image from a link is to write it in a html format as below:

```
<img src="https://cdn.coinranking.com/bOabBYkcX/bitcoin_btc.svg" style="height: 30px; width:30px;"/>
```

So in each column where you want the images to appear must be in the above html format (height and width optional but recommended)

My dash DataTable below has the icons/images of Crypto Currency besides their symbol referencing a url for the location of the icons/images.

[image: images in dash data table]

Answer (score 0):

For `dash==1.21.0`, the `markdown_options` parameter can fix this problem if you specify the image with an HTML tag. Unfortunately, this solution also creates an XSS vulnerability according to the [DataTable docs](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/reference).

Code:

```py
import dash
import dash_table

# base64 image string
img = "data:image/png;base64,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"

# add html
img = f"<img src={img}>"

# make app
data = [{"Image": img, "Text": "test"}]

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    columns=[
        {"id": name, "name": name, "presentation": "markdown"}
        for name in data[0]
    ],
    data=data,
    markdown_options={"html": True}  # dangerous but works
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Dash app screenshot:

[image: Dash app screenshot]

Another alternative is to use bootstrap: [apparently it's much easier to display an image in a table with `dbc` rather than `dash_table`](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/plotly/dash-table/383/523855054).